# Detecting active devices on LAN from Debian based server

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, debian, dhcp

Simply: How can i detect if there are any active devices on lan?

More details:
I have home server which acts as Internet gateway and wifi access point. Because of server part of its configuration i want it to run 24/7/365. Problem is, that between 9am - 5pm and +/- 11pm - 6am nobodys at home and no other device is used, so i dont need to have wifi network enabled. Between mentioned hours it just wastes energy.

Server is placed at not easy accessible place and works without display and keyboard. I want to automatize switching wifi state a bit. First thing i wanted to realize was small button with led connected to server pc by COM or USB port and small script which would retrieve signal from pressed button and switch wifi state. Unfortunately my post at electronics forum at my language was ignored so i have to drop that idea.

Now i think about some cron script which will disable wifi in defined hours if there is no active device. I thought that checking list of DHCP leases will be enough but i realised that entry in

```
/var/lib/misc/dnsmasq.leases
```

is still present after device disconnected or turned off. Im guessing that is because of lease time of 12 hours.

**So, setting a 1 hour or better 30 or 15 minutes for lease time have any disadvantages for lan network in general?** If no, is this a good idea to realize my needs or there is better method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Simply: How can i detect if there are any active devices on lan?

The answer to that is quite simple: *nmap*. You can install it from repos, then you can run it like this:

```
  sudo nmap -sn 192.168.1.0/24
```

(substitute for your own LAN) will generate a ping scan of all pcs on the network. If you suspect someone is blocking PINGs, then you may issue:

```
  sudo nmap -PA 192.168.1.0/24
  sudo nmap -PS 192.168.1.0/24
```

Or you may try to discover just about everything about a given host:

```
   sudo nmap -T5 -A 192.168.1.137
```

*nmap* is an awesome program, capable of literally thousand different tricks. It is the true instrument to discover all people on your LAN.

Comment: Thanks, now i have to find out how to easy enable wifi on time when it normally should be disabled ;)